# Heroku Not Recognizing Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have my rails app deployed on Heroku and am having trouble with the admin function. I have certain features that only admins should be able to see (creation of blog posts, etc.).  They work exactly as intended on `localhost`, but on Heroku all the users see the non-admin views.  Here's an example of the code that should distinguish the views:

```
<% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
    <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'New Blog Entry', new_post_path %></h2>
  <% else %>
    <h3 class="cta"><%= link_to 'Dig Into the Most Recent Post', post_path(@most_recent_post) %></h3>
  <% end %>
```

Here's the `enum` description for my `users` (set up with `devise`):

```
enum role: { member: 0, generator: 1, workouts: 2, all_access: 3, admin: 5 }
```

And here's the user verification in the Heroku console showing that the user is, in fact, an admin:

```
[1] pry(main)> User.first
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User:0x007f7eeed04f20
 id: 1,
...
 role: "5",
```

Does anyone have experience with Heroku to say why, when logged in as an admin, I'm still seeing the `else` condition instead of the `if` condition here? The problem is pervasive across the whole app.

Comment: Inspect `current_user.admin` to see if it's in fact true.

Comment: That's bizarre.  I'm getting `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for main:Object`

Comment: Do you have the same type of DB in local as you do on Heroku?  Have you verified that the current_user.admin? returns true?

Comment: What commands are you running at the moment you are in your project folder to execute that pry command on the heroku host?

Comment: @Jonathan I used `heroku run rails console` in my terminal.

Comment: Where are you inspecting `current_user`? Cause you can't access that in the console. `current_user` becomes available as a helper_method once the user is authenticated. You can access the helper in your controllers and views.

Comment: I'm using `devise`, so I believe `current_user` is part of the package...

Comment: Let's have at your `admin?` method please @Liz

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't write a specific admin method, other than the `enum` `:role` column on my users table.

Comment: @Liz How is devise able to interpret that your `current_user.admin?` knows to check that your `role === 5` ?

Comment: It works on `localhost`, so I assumed Heroku would be similar. How should it be structured, best practices wise?

Comment: @Liz when you say it works locally, do you mean you see the "New Blog Entry" link?

Comment: @mmichael, yes. All of the functionality keyed to `admin` works on `localhost`.

Comment: In your local `rails console` what does `User.first.admin?` produce? And on Heroku?

Comment: @mmichael, true in the local console, false in the Heroku console!

Comment: In the Heroku `console`, even if I do `User.first.admin!` (to make the user an `admin`) and it comes back `true`, then I check with `User.first.admin?` it comes back `false` again...